# Associate IAM Role with RDS instance

Tags: amazon-rds

I'm trying to add a IAM role to RDS instance via CloudFormation template. I could not find such option after looking into all attributes stated here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign role to DbInstances.

You need to create Aurora **DbCluster** (not instance) and specify the role for dbCluster. Here is the example cloudformation:

```
 "DBClusters": [
    {
        ...
        "AssociatedRoles": [
            {
                "Status": "ACTIVE",
                "RoleArn": "<role-arn>"
            }
        ],
        ...
    }
   ]
```